# How to add an extra camera so the object with the the script onBecomeInvisible() wont get destroyed when I use cinematic camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I think my title makes it obvious. I have some object setup that gets destroyed when they are not visible because of unity onbecomeinv function. I am using a virtual camera/2d camera from cinematics so now the object that are not visible are getting destroyed which they shouldnt?
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The first general "problem" with `OnBecameVisible` and `OnBecameInvisible` is that it is rendering based. This means that even if an object already left the Camera view it is possible that it still is relevant for the rendering (e.g. throwing shadows) and thus might not always behave as expected.

And secondly there is no way of knowing for exactly which camera the object became (in)visible but it rather means it became (in)visible for **(all/)any** existing cameras in the scene.

---

You can (approximately) check whether an object is partially inside a specific Camera's view frustum mathematically by using [`GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes.html) in combination with [`GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB.html)

```c#
[SerializeField] private Renderer _renderer;
[SerializeField] private Camera _camera;

private void Awake ()
{
    if(!_camera) _camera = Camera.main;
    if(!_renderer) _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
}

private void Update ()
{
    var planes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(_camera);

    if (!GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(planes, _renderer.bounds))
    {
        Debug.Log($"{name} is outside of {_camera.name}'s camera frustum!", this);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

---

This approach can be improved of course by not letting each of the object calculate this independently but rather have a general controller.

On your objects/prefabs have a class like

```c#
// Keeps track of existing instances of this component
// Provides a cached reference to the Renderer component
public class CheckVisibilityTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Each instances will (un)register itself here
    private static readonly HashSet<CheckVisibilityTarget> _instances = new HashSet<CheckVisibilityTarget>();

    // public readonly access to all existing instances of this component
    // returns a copy of _instances
    public static HashSet<CheckVisibilityTarget> Instances =>  new HashSet<CheckVisibilityTarget>(_instances);

    // Reference this already in the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Renderer _renderer;

    // public readonly access
    public Renderer Renderer => _renderer;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        // As fallback get it once on runtime
        if(!_renderer) _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();

        // Add yourself to the instances
        _instances.Add(this);
    }

    private void OnDestroy ()
    {
        // remove yourself from the instances
        _instances.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

And then as said a central controller in your scene

```c#
public class DestroyInvisibleTargets : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Reference this via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Camera _camera;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        // As fallback get it once on runtime
        if(!_camera) _camera = Camera.main;
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        // Get the planes once per frame
        var planes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(_camera);

        // Check all existing instances whether they are still within the frustum
        foreach(var target in CheckVisibilityTarget.Instances)
        {
            if (!GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(planes, target.Renderer.bounds))
            {
                Debug.Log($"{target.name} is outside of {_camera.name}'s camera frustum!", this);
                Destroy(target.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```